# KMP v.s. Suffix Tree for sub-string match

Tags: algorithm

Wondering if anyone could provide some advice about pros and cons, between choosing KMP and suffix tree, if we want to see if a string is a sub-string of another string? Thanks.

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Can you decribe your problem clearly? What's the data range?What kind  of query?

Comment: @F.Ju, I need to find if a string is a sub-string of another string. For example, "ello" is a substring of "hello". Looking forward to your advice. :)

Comment: if you only have two strings I think KMP is enough

Comment: @F.Ju, why? More details are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Runtime and memory complexity is about the same. You prepare the pattern in O(N) and you can search in O(M) (n, m lenght of your strings).

Suffix trees can do a few more operations that may not be necessary for your application.

In KMP you prepare a search pattern and then you can look for it in may strings easily.

In Suffix trees you prepare the text to search then you can look for many patterns in it easily. Even though the memory usage is linear the constant is large so this will need more memory.

KMP is in general easier to code than suffix trees.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, great answer, could you advise a bit more what do you mean "Suffix trees can do a few more operations that may not be necessary for your application"? Thanks.

Comment: And another quick question, for your comments, "You prepare the pattern in O(N) and you can search in O(M) (n, m lenght of your strings)", N is length of pattern, and M is length of source string? Thanks.

Comment: With suffix trees you can find substring repetitions( xabcyzabcq -> abc * 2) or palindromic sequences (xyzabcdcbaxyz -> abcdcba). Wikipedia has a nice summary of them.

Comment: @LinMa For KMP you prepare the search pattern, for suffix trees you prepare the search text. In both cases the operation is O(string length) and the search is O(other string lenght). For a one-off operation (one pattern to be searched in one large string) there's no benefit from the complexity perspective to pick one or the other. They are both linear.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, could you point me a reference where Wikpeedia mentioned how suffix tree could find repetitive strings?

Comment: Thanks Sorin, confused by your comments why "for suffix trees you prepare the search text", as you mentioned, "one pattern to be searched in one large string", I think in this case we should build suffix tree for the one large string, correct? Is the one large string "search text" in your context? Thanks.

Comment: BTW, Sorin, I read the tutorial on Wikipedia, and it is mentioned suffix tree could be used to find repetitive strings and palindrome, but it is not mentioned details how to achieve the goal. Appreciate if you could advise. I am referring to this page => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree, Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa yes, you build suffix tree for the large text where you are looking for patterns. To find repetitive string you pick any node (except the root), the path from the root to your node is the string that repeats. To find the number of repetitions you need to count the number of leafs in the subtree from the node you picked (each leaf is a different suffix that starts with the same characters).  For Palindrome i'm not sure about the algorithm (didn't use it so far), but I'm sure you can find suggestions on wikipedia.

Comment: thanks for the advice. For the repetitive pattern search, in your example, xabcyzabcq, where pattern abc occurs twice. For your comments, "the path from the root to your node is the string that repeats", in your example, which is root and which is the "your node"? Thanks. :)

Comment: @LinMa root, is the root of the tree (the one without any parent). The "your node" is the node that corresponds to the repeating string. For abc you need to find the node that corresponds to abc (it could be one link or more bellow the root). The path from root to the node encodes the string abc. If you look at the sub-tree you will find 2 leafs, corresponding to the suffixes abcyzabcq and abcq (in the subtree you find only yzabcq and q, since the leading abc is above the subtree we're talking about).

Comment: Thanks Sorin, smart idea. Want to confirm my understanding is correct, if a node (non-root node) has N children, it means the string it represents (from root to the node) is repeated for N times? Thanks.

Comment: Almost correct, you should count all the leafs in the subtree, not just direct children.

Comment: Thanks Sorin, nice catch. Mark your reply as answered.